# JSP: class cannot be resolved

Tags: jsp

Now I am working with one of old site that was written using JSP. And I have follow JSP:

```
<%!  Vector vUser;
    String qlAuthor;
    String qlUserId;
    String sQuery;
%>
<%  qlAuthor = (String)session.getAttribute("AUTHORITY");
    qlUserId = (String)session.getAttribute("USERID");

    if (qlAuthor.equals("admin")) {
        String role = (String)session.getAttribute("ROLE");
        String tmp  = "";

        if (role.equals("admin"))   { tmp = "0"; }
        else if (role.equals("sm")) { tmp = "3"; }
        else if (role.equals("sp")) { tmp = "6"; }

        sQuery = " MANAGERID='" + qlUserId + "' and AUTHORITY='" + tmp + "' order by (MANAGERID)";
    } else if (qlAuthor.equals("sm")) {
        sQuery = " MANAGERID='" + qlUserId +"' and AUTHORITY='6'";
    } else if (qlAuthor.equals("sp")) {
        sQuery = " AUTHORITY='9'";
    }

    vUser = BeanMember.getUserList(sQuery);
    if (session.getAttribute("VUSER") != null)
        session.removeAttribute("VUSER");

    session.setAttribute("VUSER", vUser);
%>
```

When I run this JSP I get the error:

*org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP*

An error occurred at line: 6 in the jsp file: /adminsite/user/query/qry_list.jsp
   Generated servlet error:
   BeanMember cannot be resolved

In my C:\Tomcat_5.5\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes directory I have BeanMember.class

and I have CLASSPATH=%classpath%;C:\Tomcat_5.5\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes;

but I get *BeanMember cannot be resolved* error again...

Could you please help me fix this error.

Comment: Are you sure the classpath you show is the one used by the webapp ?

Comment: @IwanKochan, did you import the class `BeanMember` inside jsp? e.g. <%@page import="package.subpackage.BeanMember"%>

Comment: How I can import BeanMember if i have not package and subpackage name? I have only BeanMember.class in folder C:\Tomcat_5.5\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes How I can import BeanMember in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you simply have an missing **Import** (to BeanMember class) in your JSP?

Import can look like following:
(this line must be put inside your JSP)

```
<%@ page import="com.path.to.BeanMember" %>
```

Comment: Ok, but I have only BeanMember.class in folder C:\Tomcat_5.5\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes How I can import BeanMember in this case?

Comment: I am try use <%@ page import="BeanMember" %> and <jsp:useBean id="BeanMember" class="BeanMember" />. And I try move BeanMember.class to С:\Working\MyApp\Beans directory and set CLASSPATH=С:\Working\MyApp\Beans but I continue get error BeanMember cannot be resolved again.